# Should I modify database table structure in a dynamic database web application?

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, database-design, ddl

I am planning to write a web application to develop custom software something similar to [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/creator/).

I think I should use DDL to dynamically add columns to tables when the user adds or removes controls from the forms. I was discussing this the other day with a friend and he suggested that modifying database structure is not a good idea. It can be very insecure as you need to give admin rights to the web application. Instead use something like MongoDB.

I am curious to know how [Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/creator/) might have implemented this. Is it really not a good idea to modify database structure from a web application?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be better off having other table with the id's of the user and the controls and some other identifiers that you might have to make them unique in your application.

You define your database and business processes beforehand and then, the information added by the users should be treated as data.

Imagine you having 200 million records and you want to add a new control. You would be adding a new value (even if it is null) to 200 million records instead of inserting a new one in a different table.

About zoho creator, you can check [this post](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/a-behind-the-scenes-look-at-zoho-creator) in a behind the scenes kind of way that you might like

Comment: It is a dynamic data management application. You cannot define the database structure/processes beforehand.

Comment: I think it still kind of applies. The part that you cannot define beforehand is the database that the user is creating, but your database should be locked beforehand. In the process of creating a table for use in their application, you store the information from the controls they select, in a table with the ids of the user, the table they are building and the id of the control and then you would make the table /column persistent when he is finished.

Comment: @Cracker of course you can. Just because the app is dynamic doesn't mean the schema has to be as well. Of course it might be that your requirements justify a different tool like MongoDB, but for that to decide you tell a little more about your requirements.